# How to modify values in xml using python?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to modify the values of xml files using python.
Here is a sample xml file

I wrote a code for adding the text to the name with iteration.

If given a set of inputs in an array, how can we check the values name
example:"Belgian Waffles" and add 2$ more price to it ?

example : array=[Strawberry Belgian Waffles,Belgian Waffles]
If "Belgian Waffles" is present
add 2$ to price

modify the price in the  elements where the name is exactly the same as the array member

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name itemid="11">Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles
with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name itemid="21">Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered
with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name itemid="31">Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>8.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with
an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name itemid="41">French Toast</name>
        <price>4.50</price>
        <description>Thick slices made from our
homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('t.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

print(myroot[0][1])

print(myroot[0].food['name'].value)

for names in myroot.iter('name'):
    names.text = names.text + ' <br> testdrive'
```

Comment: "ElementTree" provides functionality to modify the XML document and finally write it out as file.

Comment: Your array also contains `a` and `b`; do you need to check for their presence in `<name>`?

Comment: @JackFleeting A and B are just examples in an array , I just need to match the name

Comment: @MichaelButscher thats what I am going for and trying to expand the functionality to modify various elements in a node and their values

Comment: @JackFleeting thanks and I now updated the array with the values that can be matched in the given xml

Comment: I understand that, but even with the edit, it's still not clear; for example, does `Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles` also get modified or you need to modify only those `<food>` elements where the name is exactly the same as the array member?

Comment: @JackFleeting I need to modify the price in the <food>  elements where the name is exactly the same as the array member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
waffles = ["Strawberry Belgian Waffles", "Belgian Waffles"]

for food in myroot.findall('.//food'):
    item = food.find('./name').text
    if item in waffles:
        cur_price = food.find('.//price').text

        #next one is a little tricky - the price is a string on which you need
        #to perform a math function; so it needs to be converted to float and 
        #then back to string for insertion in the element

        food.find('.//price').text= str(float(cur_price)+2)
print(ET.tostring(myroot).decode())
```

Output should be what you're looking gor.

Comment: @Learn-code Glad it worked for you!

Comment: thanks for your time !! got a better understanding